# Composer error on paypal Json

Tags: json, paypal, composer-php

I am trying to enable paypal virtual purchases on my web site that should trigger some update sql queries, Yet when I try to follow the Paypal instructions at the [PayPal SDK page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)
I get a syntax error when I try to execute composer.phar on the JSON code they offer:

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.3.0",
"ext-curl": "*",
"ext-json": "*",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "0.5.*"
}
```

I get error:

```
php composer.phar update

[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
"./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 1:
"require": {    "php": ">=5.
---------^
Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

What might it be? I just downloaded composer and I do not think it is an old version.

Or otherwise, is there some tutorial about how to set the paypal purchase procedure. The one I used at http://portapipe.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/paypal-pagamenti-tramite-php-con-risposta/ does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find the source you used where they tell you how to create the `composer.json` file.

But I can tell you that if you gave the complete file contents in your question, it is in fact wrong. There is an additional set of curly braces needed to wrap all the content. Please see https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#declaring-dependencies to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. I believed paypal introduced a correct code and did not think about it too much. Of course JSON needs an embracing curled parenthesis couple, but I had no idea if for some reason composer added them itself. Of course adding them solves the problem.